# No LLC on Windows?

Tags: windows, llvm, llc

I wanted to play around with LLVM IR and installed latest LLVM v4 (on my Windows PC) but I cannot find llc in the among installed files (looked in 'bin' folder and in all others).

Wondering if this tool is not available or maybe it got deprecated or what?

Here is the content of my bin folder:

> 04/30/2017  07:46 PM              .
>
> 04/30/2017  07:46 PM              ..
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        63,566,848 clang++.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM         2,357,248 clang-apply-replacements.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        17,489,408 clang-change-namespace.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM        52,584,448 clang-check.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        63,566,848 clang-cl.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        63,566,848 clang-cpp.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM         2,380,800 clang-format.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM        20,820,480 clang-import-test.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        17,238,528 clang-include-fixer.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:34 PM         3,140,096 clang-offload-bundler.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        17,924,608 clang-query.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM        17,438,208 clang-rename.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM        17,171,456 clang-reorder-fields.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        22,490,624 clang-tidy.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM        63,566,848 clang.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        17,251,840 find-all-symbols.exe
>
> 11/08/2016  09:50 AM            20,626 git-clang-format
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        44,386,816 ld.lld.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:38 PM        55,871,488 libclang.dll
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM           574,976 libiomp5md.dll
>
> 03/09/2017  09:29 PM           574,976 libomp.dll
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        44,386,816 lld-link.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        44,386,816 lld.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:30 PM        14,962,688 llvm-ar.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        14,962,688 llvm-lib.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:37 PM        15,513,600 llvm-objdump.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:50 PM        14,962,688 llvm-ranlib.exe
>
> 03/09/2017  09:30 PM        42,117,120 LTO.dll
>
> 03/09/2017  09:35 PM        16,766,976 modularize.exe
>
> 11/14/2015  12:34 AM                23 scan-build.bat
>
> 12/21/2015  04:19 PM             4,504 scan-view

Comment: same problem here, I'm using prebuilt llvm 3.8, and no llc.exe included

Comment: Looks like you downloaded the prebuilt "Clang for Windows" installer.  The only relevant prebuilt available, LLVM is integrated into Clang.  Surely you'll need to consider building from source, LLC is available in the tools/llc subdir.  Building docs [are here](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html), don't skip bullet items 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Does some one know what stops LLVM maintainers from publishing pre-built artifact so that we don't build from sources? Any thoughts on what is behind that?

Comment: Just wondering: were you able to build _llc_ (I suppose that would fix your problem, right)?

Comment: @CristiFati -- The problem with that is the time it would take.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like llc is now embedded into clang.exe.

To generate IR Bitcode (bc):
clang -emit-llvm -c test.c

To generate IR textcode (ll):
clang -emit-llvm -S -c test.c

To compile IR to object:
clang test.bc
or
clang test.ll

Link to executable:
clang test.o -o test.exe

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but I've got a good, *working* answer. [This](https://github.com/CRogers/LLVM-Windows-Binaries) repo on GitHub has the built binaries for windows. It comes with:

- `llc`
- `lli`
- `llvm-dis`
- and so much more!

Comment: This repo was last updated in 2014, and contains LLVM 3.4 binaries. LLVM is up to 11 today.

Comment: @nyanpasu64 -- Yes you are right. It is better than nothing though.

Comment: These files are somewhat useless, since llc from Clang 10 won't process files from Clang 11 (I didn't try changing the version field of my .bc). I did manage to build them myself, and I *could* upload (though users may run into msvcrt DLL issues).

Comment: @nyanpasu64 Hi, would you be willing to set up similar GitHub repo with the latest LLVM build(s) for Windows? Or at least, share it anyhow, please. I would also like to have the full tools suite (including `llc`) but am not experienced enough to build it from source.

Comment: I found much newer build 9.0.0 from 2019 [here](https://github.com/vovkos/llvm-package-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Ziglang provides **NEW** prebuilt LLVM toolchain (13.0.1) for Windows, including `llc`:

[image: llvm]

You can download it [here](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Building-Zig-on-Windows#option-2-using-cmake-and-microsoft-visual-studio) or direct link [here](https://ziglang.org/deps/llvm%2bclang%2blld-13.0.1-x86_64-windows-msvc-release-mt.tar.xz)